# I divided my html page into half using width and %, but it looks like there is still overlap in the Chrome inspector?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive blog. Here is my code for my two halves:

```
.masthead {
  background-color: $hot-orange;
  float:left;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 32%;

  @include mobile {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.main-body {
  float: right;
  width: 68%
}
```

Here is the container that is wrapping both:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1250px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? When I open the inspector and highlight both halves, it looks like the right half (the main-body) overlaps with the left slightly. I can't seem to find the issue.

Here is my [repo](https://github.com/Jwan622/Jwan622.github.io)

Comment: as the left side is fixed and the right isn't it would suggest to me that you haven't removed the margin from the body tag? `body{margin:0;}`

Comment: Also float has no effect on a fixed element! perhaps you should remove the width on the `.main-body` and add `padding-left: 32%` instead